# Python Requests Cannot Post Data On Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-requests

I am trying to login using Python Requests Library.
When i run it on Windows All goes ok.
But when i try it on Linux(same python version(3.5)) it fails
I tried everything but it gives me the same result.

**This are the post data i send**

usernamefield = rsnewuser

password field = rsnewpass

yes, i checked if there are some hidden inputs.

**The problem on linux**: When I put some invalid data then the html returns that the data is invalid. But when I put in the valid data then It fails and returns the output of the login page.

My Python Code:

```
import requests

    payload = {
        'rsnewuser': 'user',
        'rsnewpass': 'pass'
    }

    with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post('http://somesite.com/admin.php', data=payload)
        print(p.text)
        r = s.get("http:/somesite.cz/admin.php")
        print (r.text)
```

As I said this problem is only when I am on linux, this code works good on Windows.

My English is not good, but i hope you get my question.

Comment: This script sends post request as expected. It returns you the login page, so network works. Find something that makes it different from Windows. Check actual network data, network setup. Maybe some fields in the HTTP header are different and the server does not accept it due to some filtering rules. Proxy, some issues with SSL in case of HTTPS...

Comment: Ok. I will check it out. Thanks. @OrestHera